# scipy: where to find source code for scipy.special.betainc?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to get under the hood of [`stats.pearsonr`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2940-L3022) for my own understanding. I would like to write `r, p = stats.pearsonr(x, y)` as some stand alone code (see below). I am able to reproduce `r`, however the p-value calculation makes use of `scipy.special.betainc`. I had a rummage in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/special but couldn't find `betainc` (i'm guessing it may be some underlying C code). Any idea where I can find the source code for this?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

n = len(x)
mx = x.mean()
my = y.mean()
xm, ym = x - mx, y - my
r_num = np.add.reduce(xm * ym)
r_den = np.sqrt(np.sum(xm*xm, 0) * np.sum(ym*ym, 0))
r = r_num / r_den
r = max(min(r, 1.0), -1.0)

df = n - 2
if abs(r) == 1.0:
    p = 0.0
else:
    t_squared = r**2 * (df / ((1.0 - r) * (1.0 + r)))
    # Now code https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/14142ff70d84a6ce74044a27919c850e893648f7/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3020
    _x = df/(df+t_squared)
    _x = np.asarray(_x)
    _x = np.where(_x < 1.0, _x, 1.0)
    _a = 0.5*df
    _b = 0.5
    # Code special.betainc(_a, _b, _x)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.special.betainc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scipy.special.betainc` is based on `incbet` in [`scipy/special/cephes/incbet.c`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/special/cephes/incbet.c), a function from the Cephes Math Library.

I found this by [searching](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=betainc&type=) for `betainc` in the SciPy Github repository, which lead me to [`scipy/special/functions.json`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/special/functions.json#L201), which lead me to `incbet`.